# I sent shib tokens to the contract address

Tags: etherscan, cancel-transaction

I have sent somehow 199 M shib tokens to the contract address

How can reverse the transaction and get my shib tokens back ?

Here is the trx:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa1e098bd43b5fb2d90c715c301cf5510cdbd9efe27539b92ffd6b546dfe3fecc

thank you

Answer (score 1):

This transaction failed and, therefore, your tokens weren't transferred out of your account.

If the transaction had been confirmed, there would be no way of reverting it. You can check this on the [transaction life-cycle](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/#transaction-lifecycle).